# Design option for Heavy DB Read and Write operation

Tags: java, scalability

I have a system which sends messages to millions of user.

We have 6 application nodes in a cluster with one common oracle data base(RAC).

In one of the usecase, we have to send message to user and once it is delivered, we have to update a counter in db table which has the detail of no. of messages sent to an user.
We also have a constraint that we have to send only 'n' number of messages to an user in a day.

`So,
1) Every time before sending the message, we have to read the database to fetch the counter value.
2) Every time after sending the message,we have to update the counter.`

Any node can receive the message for any user and it can read and update the DB in parallel.

Now, the issue we are facing is each node couldn't handle more than 1K messages per second. During peak load, all threads are either reading or updating DB.

We are thinking of introduction of a cache mechanism to avoid DB calls. But, since here write to DB is also huge, we feel cache may not be the correction solution.

Do you have any better suggestion or architecture to handle this usecase with both heavy read and write operation on DB ? What solution you would suggest if you face this situation ?

Please let me me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to cut the applications from your database completely.
Instead, have them post jobs on a queue. Have queue workers take jobs from the queue, read/write the database and post the results to some form of result cache. Applications can then poll the result cache for their results.

While this doesn't reduce your database read/writes, it allows you to layer your overall application. As an example, you could have a layer for filtering the jobs on the queue, bundle together multiple counter updates and have a worker write them all in one go.

The other obvious possibility would be to take a good look at your architecture and decide whether changing the database technology would be desireable. If you don't overly rely on joins, complex SQL queries, etc. have a look at key-value stores or NoSQL. Have a look at Cassandra for performance.

[This interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJ-Bu8gQgOc) is about the architecture of Reddit and it might give you some nice ideas. (It also shows the worker/queue approach that I mentioned)